# iPhone subview flip between 2 views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, subview, flip

iPhone / Objective-C

On my view a little "hover" view appears after a user clicks on a button on the main view. When the user clicks this subview I want the subview to FlipFromRight to another view (same size). The main view underneath should stay.

**viewHot** and **viewCold** are the subviews **viewMain** is the main one.

Is this possible?

Comment: I have used the following code..it works fine..but one problem.. I have a tableView in viewHot. When "else" part get executed viewHot appears. But coldView is still behind the viewHot so when I scroll tableView to maximum or minimum the coldView is seen.. any guesses ?

Comment: I tried removeFromSuperView , hidden = YES etc but no Luck.. !!!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Create another empty view in viewMain called viewHover and position it where you want the hover views to show.  Then in IB add either viewHot or viewCold (not both) as a subview of viewHover.

Then call a method like this to flip the views:

```
-(void)flipViews
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];  
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:viewHover cache:YES];

    if ([viewHot superview])
    {
        [viewHot removeFromSuperview];
        [viewHover addSubview:viewCold];
        [viewHover sendSubviewToBack:viewHot];
    }
    else
    {
        [viewCold removeFromSuperview];
        [viewHover addSubview:viewHot];
        [viewHover sendSubviewToBack:viewCold];
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: This code helped me in presenting a small modal view.
Thank you.

Comment: Just an FYI, with the new animation blocks the animation can be one-lined: [UIView transitionFromView:viewHot toView:viewCold duration:1.f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:nil];